# How to create a divider after specific number of rows in a GridView of Android?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I need to create a GridView consisting of type1, type2 and type3 having same UI but different properties. I am adding all type of contents in a single gridview with order like first all type1 elements then type2 elements. I need to create a divider between type1 and type2. How can we add divider between items of a gridview after specific row of gridview.

One way in which i know it can be done is using 3 gridviews having divider in between them. Can we use a single gridview having dividers in between the rows at specific position ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course we could.
You can add an empty view with certain height on the bottom of type 1 view which at most of time it's "gone", and when it became the last one of type 1 view ,you can set it to visible. 
There you create a divider.